# How does cp -a work

Tags: files, copy

I am trying to understand linux and working through some tutorials. One states that I can copy files to the current directory by using a `cp -a` command with a relative pathname such as

```
cp -a ../somedir/.
```

It fails each time I run it. Is the syntax incorrect?
I tried the man page, but it didn't seem to find anything that answers my question.

Comment: you are missing a blank space between somedir and the last dot. See vidarlo 's answer, it is correct. Upvote it! Accept it!

Comment: Also something I wish I had known a whole lot earlier when learning Linux & bash is that you can press tab to get autocomplete; press it twice for suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cp -a ../somedir/.` is wrong. The general syntax is

```
cp source target
```

You only specified one argument. To copy something to current directory, you can run

```
cp ../somedir .
```

Note the space before the dot. `.` is shorthand for current directory. `..` is shorthand for parent directory.

Comment: -a "preserves" everything and recurses. There is a man page for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

`cp -a ../somedir  .`
if you want to copy the folder it self with its content

Or you can say

`cp -a ../somedir/* .` 
If you want to copy the content of the folder.

the `-a` option will try to clone the same file structure with the same file tree to the new location